# Unit testing AngularJS controller with $httpBackend

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, controller

For the life of me I can't get $httpBackend to work on a controller that does an $http get request.  I've tried for hours now =)

I've reduced this to the simplest form I can below.  The test passes if I

- comment out the $http.get() request in the controller
- comment out the "httpMock.flush()" in the test
- and change "pig" and "dog" to match

That is, it's a valid, working test and app.

If I put it back in, I get the error shown at the bottom.

---

*app/js/app.js*

```
// Declare a module which depends on filters and services.
var myApp = angular
  .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myApp.filters', 'myApp.services',
                              'myApp.directives'])
  .config(['$routeProvider' , function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
      .when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "partials/dashboard.html",
        controller: cDashboard
      })

      .otherwise({redirectTo: "/dashboard"});
  }]);

// Pre-define our main namespace modules.
angular.module('myApp.directives' , []);
angular.module('myApp.filters'    , []);
angular.module('myApp.services'   , []);
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []);
```

*app/js/controller.js*

```
function cDashboard ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = "dog";

  // Fetch the actual data.
  $http.get("/data")
    .success(function (data) { $scope.data = data })
    .error(function () {});
}

cDashboard.$inject = [ '$scope', '$http' ];
```

*test/unit/controllerSpec.js*

```
describe('cDashboard', function(){
  var scope, ctrl, httpMock;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $http, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('cDashboard', {$scope: scope});

    httpMock = $httpBackend;
    httpMock.when("GET", "/data").respond("pig");
  }));

  it("should get 'pig' from '/data'", function () {
    httpMock.expectGET("/data").respond("pig");
    expect(scope.data).toBe("pig");
  });

});
```

And this is the error I get in the shell:

```
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/home/myApp/test/unit/controller/cDashboard.js".
Chrome 26.0 (Linux) cDashboard should get 'pig' from '/data' FAILED
    Error: No pending request to flush !
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at Function.$httpBackend.flush (/home/myApp/test/lib/angular/angular-mocks.js:1171:34)
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/myApp/test/unit/controller/cDashboard.js:15:18)
Chrome 26.0 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0.326 secs / 0.008 secs)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a couple problems in your test code:

1. The controller is created *before* the `httpMock` is configured to respond with `pig`. The `expectGet` call should happen before instantiating the controller.
2. The `httpMock` needs to flush the request
3. The `httMock.when` is unnecessary so long as you have the `expectGet`

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lUkDMrsy1KJNai3ndtng?p=preview

```
describe('cDashboard', function(){
  var scope, controllerService, httpMock;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controllerService = $controller;
    httpMock = $httpBackend;
  }));

  it("should get 'pig' from '/data'", function () {
    httpMock.expectGET("/data").respond("pig");
    ctrl = controllerService('cDashboard', {$scope: scope});
    httpMock.flush();
    expect(scope.data).toBe("pig");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  The plunk and the explanation that the .expectGET has to happen before instantiating the controller help immensely.