# Testing functions with only http request in karma?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, service, karma-jasmine

I have to test an AngularJS app and I am trying to do the unit testing for the services. The services have functions that look like this:

```
      getData: function(){
      return $http.get(serviceRoot+'/getData/'+anotherService.id()).then(function(response) {
              return secondService.validateServerJson(response.data.key);
      }, function(error) {
        return false;
      })
    },
```

is there a point to write a test for this since I am mocking the http requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
$httpBackend.expectGET(serviceRoot+'/getData/'+anotherService.id(), function(){}).respond(200,{/*response object*/});
yourserviceinstance.getData();
$httpBackend.flush();
```

here is the link 
[Unit testing AngularJS controller with $httpBackend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427968/unit-testing-angularjs-controller-with-httpbackend)

hope this may help you